# How do I scroll faster in general on iOS?

Tags: ios, ui, macos

The general scrolling is way too slow and unsuitable for large articles or pages. I want a way to grab a scrollbar on the side of a page (just like on a laptop/desktop operating system) and use that to scroll through large articles and pages.

There's no reason why I should have to manually scroll through 300 pages, 1 page at a time.

Comment: The iOS user interface on iPhones and iPads differ somewhat, so it might be worth clarifying what device you're asking about, and the version of iOS installed. Also, are you asking about a particular app (e.g. Safari, etc) or a particular document type (e.g. PDF, etc)?

Comment: Mainly asking about iPhone. No particular app. I'm looking for a general solution.